# Calculating and appending values to new column in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm quite new to R and I have a question about working with data frames.

Let's say I have a data set about users who watched movies. It's in the following format:

```
DATAFRAME 1:

UserId  |  MovieId 
1       |  101
1       |  102
1       |  103
2       |  101
2       |  102
3       |  101
3       |  103
```

I have a second data frame in the same format, but consisting only of 1 target user:

```
DATAFRAME 2:

UserId  |  MovieId 
10      |  101
10      |  102
10      |  103
10      |  234
```

I would like to create two new columns in the DATAFRAME 1.

In the first column, I would like to take the number of movies that each user has *in common* with the target user in DATAFRAME 2, divided by the total number of movies in DATAFRAME 2. For example, user 1 should have a value of 0.75, because he has watched 3 of the same movies as target user 10, divided by the 4 movies that target user 10 has watched.

In the second column, I would like to take 1 divided by the number of movies each user has watched. For example, for user 1 it should be 1/3.

The final data frame should look like this:

```
DATAFRAME 1:

UserId  |  MovieId | Var1 |  Var2
1       |  101     | 0.75 |  0.333
1       |  102     | 0.75 |  0.333
1       |  103     | 0.75 |  0.333
2       |  101     | 0.5  |  0.5
2       |  102     | 0.5  |  0.5    
3       |  101     | 0.5  |  0.5
3       |  103     | 0.5  |  0.5
```

How might I accomplish this?

And secondly, is there a way to accomplish this without a for loop, if my data frame is large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>% 
  group_by(UserId) %>%
  mutate(
    Var1 = sum(MovieId %in% DF2$MovieId) / nrow(DF2),
    Var2 = 1 / n()
  )
```

This assumes that both data frames do not have duplicate rows.

Comment: I'm glad someone understood the problem statement.